# Asyc API method

Tags: web-services, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, async-await

I'am working on a project that exposes a Web Api for Encrypting files and doing other tasks. What I want is to make the encryption task async, this is because files could be of size more than 1GB, and I donot want the client to keep waiting for the file to be encrypted. What I want is that once request for encryption is sent to the api the client is notified that your request is accepted and when it finishes a notification about success or failure is sent to the client again. Meanwhile client can do anything.
What are the best practices for this, moreover Iam working in asp.net mvc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **off load** the encryption task to another thread in your serve. This will free up (complete) the request processing thread, and the client can continue with other stuff. You can wrap the encryption task such that after successful completion or failure, a **callback** is invoked. This callback must be responsible for notifying the client back.

**To notify the client back,** upon completion of the encryption task, you have several options, that you must code within your callback:

1. *Email* the client of the result.
2. If the client is a service and listens on a specific port, you can *accept a callback URL in the initial encryption request*, and can invoke this URL after encryption task. The assumption is that the client is running a http Service.
3. If there are any *other integration points* with the client (like filesystem, database, message oriented middleware), then use those to notify of task completion.

Comment: Do you recommend the use of AJAX for this purpose ?

Comment: Client can be any thing, android , IOS , a web client, what should be the notification mechanism than ?

Comment: We can use push messages for android/IOS apps. For a browser based client, AJAX can be used for polling the server for message that can let the client know if the task is completed (or completed with error). If the message is intended for a *user*, and the process takes really long, then we must notify over email mechanism; this will allow the user to close the browser without waiting for the result.